# Вывод благодарности после отправки формы

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый день. У меня к Вам, профи, такой вопрос. Как сделать такую вещь? Расскажу в двух словах: у меня есть форма-заявка, она всплывашка, когда вызывается она, то идет валидация формы и отправка данных в случае успешного заполнения. Моя задача сделать, чтобы после отправки формы (после нажатия кнопки субмит) она какое-то время не закрывалась и появлялось сообщение на ней с благодарностью о заказе. Как это сделать?

Пока в субмите у меня так все:

```
$("#id_form").submit(function(event){ //Обрабатываем сабмит формы

            var var1 = true; // переменная валидации

             if ($('#name').val().length) // если длина имени больше 0
             {
                $('#name').css( "border-color","#34BDD6"); //css('border', '#34BDD6');              
             } 
             else // если пусто поле
             {
                var1 = false;               
                $('#name').css("border-color", '#FF0000');                                  
             }

             if ($('#email').val().length > 5) // если почтовый больше нуля
             {
                $('#email').css('border-color', '#34BDD6');
             } 
             else // если пустое поле
             {
                var1 = false;               
                $('#email').css('border-color', '#FF0000');
             }

             if (var1==false) // если отправить данные формы нельзя (пустые поля)
             {
               event.preventDefault();
               return false;
             }
             else // если отправляем данные, пишем благодарность и таймер
             {
                $("#id_title_form").text = "Спасибо за заказ! В ближайшее время мы свяжемся с Вами!";               
                setTimeout(function(){alert('Привет'); return true;}, 1500);                
             }
           });
```

Вот, собственно, что у меня не получается. Подскажите, как можно такую вещь реализовать?

По коду вызова/сокрытия окна все выглядит так:

```
  $('a#go').click( function(event){ // ловим клик по ссылки с id="go"
            event.preventDefault(); // выключаем стандартную роль элемента
            $('#overlay').fadeIn(400, // сначала плавно показываем темную подложку
             function(){ // после выполнения предъидущей анимации
                $('#modal_form') 
                    .css('display', 'block') // убираем у модального окна display: none;
                    .animate({opacity: 1, top: '50%'}, 200); // плавно прибавляем прозрачность одновременно со съезжанием вниз
            });
          });

          /* Закрытие модального окна, тут делаем то же самое но в обратном порядке */
          $('#modal_close, #overlay').click(function(){ // ловим клик по крестику или подложке
           $('#modal_form')
            .animate({opacity: 0, top: '45%'}, 200,  // плавно меняем прозрачность на 0 и одновременно двигаем окно вверх
                function(){ // после анимации
                    $(this).css('display', 'none'); // делаем ему display: none;
                    $('#overlay').fadeOut(400); // скрываем подложку
                }
            );
           });
```

Comment: @MasterAlex, разницы нет, что так или так, я просто в заголовок формы клал это сообщение. Результат один и тот, форма отправляется и закрывается, никакой задержки в таймауте нет и соответственно вывода заголовка тоже нет.

Comment: @IntegralAL, поищите в JS, где у вас происходит событие закрытия попапа при отправке формы, в предложенном выше коде этого нет